# How to shift values in an array to the left by 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, eclipse

Im trying to shift the values in the array to the left by 3. The point that I am trying to make is to make the whole code rotate to the left.

```
double[] x = {38, 44, 15, 11, 27, 19, 8, 12, 10};
      System.out.println("Before rotation:  ==============================");
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("x[" + i + "]:  " + x[i]);
      }
      x = rotate(x, 3);
      System.out.println("After rotation:  ==============================");       
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length-3; i++)
      {

          System.out.println("x[" + i + "]:  " + x[i]);

}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of `rotate()` function you are using here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code demonstrates how you can rotate an array.

First `arraycopy()` call copies the latter part of the array (from `rotateBy` to the end). Second `arraycopy()` call copies the beginning part of the array (from begging up to `rotateBy`).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Rotate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] input = {8, 4, 5, 21, 7, 9, 18, 2, 100};
    double[] output = rotate(input, 3);
    System.out.println("Input:  " + Arrays.toString(input));
    System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.toString(output));
  }

  public static double[] rotate(double[] inputArray, int rotateBy) {
    double[] output = new double[inputArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(inputArray, rotateBy, output, 0, inputArray.length - rotateBy);
    System.arraycopy(inputArray, 0, output, inputArray.length - rotateBy, rotateBy);
    return output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

```
public class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] initial = {8, 4, 5, 21, 7, 9, 18, 2, 100};
    double[] shifted = new double[initial.length];
    System.arraycopy(initial, 3, shifted, 0, initial.length - 3);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shifted));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The only problem with this one is that it did shift the numbers to the left by 3, but it didn't add the first 3 numbers to the end, instead, it replaced it with zeroes, which is my fault completely since I didn't specify it